# MVC models' unique field Create-Edit Complication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have a model in MVC like that;

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [DisplayName("Email")]
        [Remote("doesEmailExist", "Employee", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Email already exists. Please enter a different Email.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

On create action, that is okey, it works great. But on edit action, program see email address already exist. And I cannot update my employee with the same email address. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `AdditionalFields` property of `RemoteAttribute` to include `EmployeeId` in the validation. Then in your action method, if `EmployeeId=null` validation fails if a matching email is found, otherwise only check for matching emails where its a different EmployeeID

Comment: I did method like that;                                                                                               [HttpPost]
public JsonResult doesEmailExist(int EmployeeId, string Email){}       when i edit it it returns id and mail and it works well but when i create new one it doesnt see this method

Comment: Does EmployeeID have a value for a new employee (e.g. = 0) or is it null? If null then the it should be `doesEmailExist(int? EmloyeeID, ..`